# Sort conditional data in Postgres STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I've come up with a query to create concatenated string based on a conditional statement using `STRING_AGG` in Postgress. That works just fine but I want to sort the result as well without duplicating the `CASE`.

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT
STRING_AGG(distinct name, ', ' ORDER BY name),
STRING_AGG(
  DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN something = true THEN 'type1'
       WHEN something_else = true THEN 'type2'
       ELSE 'type3'
  END, ', '
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN something = true THEN 'type1'
       WHEN something_else = true THEN 'type2'
       ELSE 'type3'
  END

)
from organisations
```

..but I want to do something like this to not have the duplicated code and remove rows and complexity from my query but I can't figure out how to make it work, this is fake code that doesn't work obviously, but you get the idea:

```
SELECT
STRING_AGG(distinct name, ', ' ORDER BY name) names,
STRING_AGG(
  DISTINCT (
    CASE WHEN something = true THEN 'type1'
         WHEN something_else = true THEN 'type2'
         ELSE 'type3'
    END
  ) as types, ', ' ORDER BY types) types
from organisations
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require `string_agg()`.  You could instead do:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(distinct name, ', ' ORDER BY name) names,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 (CASE WHEN SUM( (something = true)::int ) > 0 THEN 'type1'),
                 (CASE WHEN SUM( (not (something = true) )::int ) > 0 THEN 'type2')
                ) as types
FROM organisations o;
```

You may have oversimplified the query, but for what you provided, you don't need `string_agg(distinct)` for the second portion.

Comment: That is great, I could make your suggestion work for me, I would not have figured that one out myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to compute the `CASE` expression first in a separate CTE, and then query that CTE to apply `STRING_AGG`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        CASE WHEN something = true THEN 'type1'
             WHEN something_else = true THEN 'type2'
             ELSE 'type2'
        END AS expr
    FROM organisations
)

SELECT
    STRING_AGG(distinct name, ', ' ORDER BY name),
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT expr, ', ' ORDER BY expr)
FROM cte;
```

As a minor side note, since you have `type2` as both the second and `ELSE` condition in the `CASE` expression, you might as well just use this:

```
CASE WHEN something = true THEN 'type1'
     ELSE 'type2'
END
```

Comment: Actually, the `type2` in in the `ELSE` was a typo, thanks for pointing that out, I've not corrected it.